# How can I boot to upstart failsafe mode?

Tags: boot, upstart

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#failsafe-mode-ubuntu-specific

says 11.10 introduced a new failsafe mode. How can I boot to it? What commands do I give grub to pass to upstart to do this failsafe thing. What IS this failsafe thing? how is it different from Recovery Mode? It seems the upstart cookbook is lacking in this area.

Comment: You just asked the same question a couple hours back.

Comment: No, this is a very different question. Previous question is in regards to a recovery console. This is in regards to "failsafe mode" according to the cookbook these are two different things.

Comment: Well, the posts are very much related. I advise combining the two questions into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jay, failsafe mode isn't all that interesting. With Ubuntu 10.04 - 11.04, the system would boot into "multi user" mode before all "static" network connections were available. This is fine for a laptop or desktop, because NetworkManager manages connections in a way where most GUI programs are ready to have their network connection gone. But for servers, this is unacceptable, as some of the network services require there to be a specific network configuration before they start.

The failsafe mode is just a way to get the system to continue booting, even if these network interfaces are not available. Its essentially a timeout after 2 minutes of waiting, nothing more.